# Returning Dynamic List or Dictionary in c#

Tags: c#

I have a function which can return me multiple key,value objects. I am not sure how to do that.

```
 public static List <String> organizationType(User user)
    {
        List<String> data = new List<String>();
            foreach (UserRoles ur in user.GetUserRoles())
            {
                OrganizationType ot = OrganizationType.Get(ur.organizationTypeId, "1");
                data.Add(ot.Name); // I would need a key here as well
                data.Add(ur.roleTypeId);
                data.Add(ur.organizationId);

            }


        return data;
    }
```

What I want is some think like

```
var objs = organizationType(...);

for (var i in objs){
   objs[var].Name; // something like this
}
```

Can I return JSON? Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: You already said it yourself, return a Dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your need, this is what I would do:

```
public static IEnumerable<string[]> organizationType(User user)
{
    foreach (UserRoles ur in user.GetUserRoles())
    {
        OrganizationType ot = OrganizationType.Get(ur.organizationTypeId, "1");
        string[] data = new string[] { ot.Name, ur.roleTypeId, ur.organizationId };
        yield return data;
    }
}
```

But as being said in the comments above, you can also use a simple dictionary to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ query:

```
    public static IEnumerable<string[]> GetOrganizationType(User user)
    {
        return from ur in user.GetUserRoles()
               let ot = OrganizationType.Get(ur.organizationTypeId, "1")
               select new[] {ot.Name, ur.roleTypeId, ur.organizationId};
    }
```

or method chain:

```
    public static IEnumerable<string[]> GetOrganizationType(User user)
    {
        return user.GetUserRoles()
                   .Select(ur => new[]
                                 {
                                     OrganizationType.Get(ur.organizationTypeId, "1").Name,
                                     ur.roleTypeId,
                                     ur.organizationId
                                 });
    }
```

but anyway I suggest to use Dictionary. You need something like this:

```
    public static Dictionary<OrganizationType, UserRoles> GetOrganizationType(User user)
    {
        return user.GetUserRoles().ToDictionary(ur => OrganizationType.Get(ur.organizationTypeId, "1"),
                                                ur => ur);
    }
```